# If file exists on multiple computers write to txt file

Tags: vbscript

hey guys needs some help! i am trying to do the same sort of thing. 
What im trying to do is check to see the a certain application is installed on the computers in the txt file 
and if its not installed the write those computers names to another text file called not installed

my code so far:
Note it works 75% (only writes 1 line in the not installed.txt)

```
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objtext = FSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Jabber Testing\Asset_List.txt")

Do Until objtext.AtEndOfStream
Asset = objtext.ReadLine
InstallPath = "\\" & Asset & "\C$\Program Files (x86)\Cisco Systems\Cisco Jabber\CiscoJabber.exe"
If not FSO.FileExists (InstallPath) Then
outFile="c:\Jabber Testing\Not Installed.txt"
Set objFile = FSO.CreateTextFile(outFile,True)
objFile.Write Asset & vbCrLf
objFile.Close
End If
Loop
objtext.Close
```

Can some one please help me with this have a intermediate understanding with vbs and need to sort through about 2000 computers

Answer (score 0):

The value **True** in `Set objFile = FSO.CreateTextFile(outFile,True)` causes [the file will be overwritten](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5t9b5c0c(v=vs.84).aspx). Open output file *before* `Do Until ... Loop` as follows:

```
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objtext = FSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Jabber Testing\Asset_List.txt")

outFile="c:\Jabber Testing\Not Installed.txt"
Set objFile = FSO.CreateTextFile(outFile,True)

Do Until objtext.AtEndOfStream
  Asset = objtext.ReadLine
  InstallPath = "\\" & Asset & _
    "\C$\Program Files (x86)\Cisco Systems\Cisco Jabber\CiscoJabber.exe"
  If not FSO.FileExists (InstallPath) Then
    objFile.Write Asset & vbCrLf
  End If
Loop
objtext.Close
objFile.Close
```